# Debian 9: Audio Issues

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I've just installed a fresh new Debian 9 LXDE into an Acer AMD notebook and it seems that all the audio devices were correctly recognized:

```
root@debian:~# aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: CX20584 Analog [CX20584 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

However, none of these devices are working properly:

- only a few stuff plays on the headphones, ex:
  `speaker-test --device plughw:1,0`
  `aplay --device plughw:1,0 test.wav`
  system beep
- only a few stuff plays on the HDMI, ex:
  `speaker-test --device plughw:0,3`
  `aplay --device plughw:0,3 test.wav`
  system beep
- no sound from the speakers
- no volume icon in the bottom task bar

**Question**

- Could this be a sound routing issue?
- Setting the main audio device as default could solve this issue?
- How to solve that? Any other idea?

---

**Notebook Specifications**
[Aspire E1-421-0622](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4095)

- AMD 2 Core™ Processor E1-1200 (1.4 GHz) 1MB Cache 64-bit Processing
- AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics Controller
- 2Gb DDR3 SDRAM Memory
- 256MB shared video memory
- Atheros HB125 IEEE 802.11b/g/n Fast Ethernet Network Card

**Debian Version**
[debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso)

- Small CDs
- AMD64 processor architecture
- DVD burnt via Win7
- Non-free package `firmware-amd-graphics` installed
  [radeon kernel modesetting for R600 or later requires firmware-amd-graphics](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/8nz4pw/error_radeon_kernel_modesetting_for_r600/)

**Software selection**

(  ) Debian desktop environment
(  ) ... GNOME
(  ) ... Xfce
(  ) ... KDE
(  ) ... Cinnamon
(  ) ... MATE
(X) ... LXDE
(  ) web server
(  ) print server
(  ) SSH server
(X) standard system utilities

Comment: Mixer/sound routing issues. Cannot help further.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Maybe it is something simpler. Ex: The default audio is set to HDMI instead of speaker. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: That could be a sound routing issue. In my Lenovo in openbsd was set for the headphones only by default. Sound is not my specialty, not able to help

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Do you think that the latest kernel from backports might be the direction?

Comment: Nah, some sysctl or alsa settings. Não o consigo ajudar mais que isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, alsa is loading the correct modules but setting the wrong sound device as default.

Assign card 1 to index=0 with `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf` containing:

```
alias char-major-116 snd
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias snd-card-1 snd-hda-intel

options snd-hda-intel id=Generic_1 index=0
options snd-hda-intel id=Generic index=1
```

After rebooting, the main audio device should be the default:

```
root@debian:~# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: CX20584 Analog [CX20584 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Open a terminal and confirm in `alsamixer` that all channels are unmuted.
Speakers, headphones and HDMI should be working now.

---

Source: [Audio and snd-hda-intel](https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel)